# Error detection in basic code

Tags: python

There is some error in my code and I am unable to detect what it is. I am looking for this result: `[0.25 , 0.4 , 0.5]`

Below is my code:

```
def divide_list (list1 , list2 ):

list_out = []
for number1 in list1 :
for number2 in list2 :
list_out . append ( number1 / number2 )
return list_out

# Test case
print divide_list ([1 ,2 ,3] ,[4 ,5 ,6])
```

Comment: And what result do you get instead?

Comment: (1.) Please fix your indentation, so we can run your code. (2.) Please provide actual and expected output.

Comment: What is your error? You have to provide this basic information if you reasonably expect an answer. [ask]

Comment: @jonrsharpe: why removing ALL of the indenting? Now the code's even more broken.

Comment: @MarcB I restored it to the OP's original (no) indenting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: ah yeah, serves me right for not having looked at the edit history.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all, you appear to have an IndentationError and there are extra space around the dot:

```
def divide_list(list1, list2):
    list_out = []
    for number1 in list1:
        for number2 in list2:
            list_out.append(float(number1) / float(number2))
    return list_out

# Test case
print divide_list([1 ,2 ,3], [4 ,5 ,6])
```

I also added some PEP 8 formatting. Next time, try giving the answerer some information about the problem.

- Indentation is required in python
- By default in Python 2 dividing an integer by an integer always returns an integer
- Pay attention to code formatting - see the changes I made to make the code look better. In general pay attention to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Hi CrazyPython, Thanks for your inputs. So by doing this small change and changing the type to Float I will be getting [0.25 , 0.4 , 0.5] output ? Anyway yo can check that?

Comment: @Liza.N Yes, I can paste it in to a python file and run it.

Comment: Great..Thank you so much for your help.:)

Comment: @Liza.N Accept the answer and upvote it if you think it was useful :)

Comment: "By default in Python 3 dividing an integer by an integer always returns an integer" Do you mean in Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 uses floor division for integers by default. You can either use `from __future__ import division` to force all division to produce floats by default, or you can coerce one or more of the numbers to float, using the `float()` constructor, or by adding in a float operation that preserves equality (`0.0 + x`, `1.0 * x`, etc).